# .htaccess allow hotlinking for one specific folder

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, referrer, hotlinking

I'll get straight to it. I have this code in my .htaccess file to prevent hotlinking, see below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mywebsite.ca/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mywebsite.ca$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.mywebsite.ca/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.mywebsite.ca$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ - [F,NC]
```

but I will have a few .jpg images up for banner exchange between sites and I don't know how to write the rule to allow hotlinking for just one folder. In this case the one folder will be `root/image/links/`

What changes in the rewrite conditions do I need to make to allow hotlinking for this one folder?

Thanks for your anticipated help everyone.

Comment: I am aware of the method where putting another htaccess file in that folder and including `RewriteEngine off` but I am not sure if that will leave this folder vulnerable in some way?

Comment: try adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/root/image/links/` or what ever URI is

Comment: would this be correct? `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^http://www.mywebsite.ca/image/links/`

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/image/links` only.

Comment: yes it worked, thank you Dexa, if you like add that response to an answer and i will check it answered.

Comment: oh, I do have another question, similar topic. If I were to put an htaccess file in a specific folder and included `RewriteEngine off` would this leave the folder vulnerable in anyway from being hacked or used as a means of injecting code into my site?

Comment: I guess that question is too broad, it depends on your server configuration. Also depends on your other code.

Comment: Ah ok, I will look into more, thanks for your help Dexa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/image/links/
```

as an additional condition.